# Neo4Django - SyncDB does not create table and graph

Tags: python, django, neo4django

I am using Neo4Django in my django based application and trying to use two databases at the sametime : Neo4j and PostGIS. So I configured settings.py as suggested in the docs (http://neo4django.readthedocs.org) and models.py as well.

When I try to run syncdb , I get this message

```
You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have any superusers defined.
    Would you like to create one now? (yes/no): yes
    Username (leave blank to use 'postgres'): 
    E-mail address: postgres@gmail.com
    Password: 
    Password (again): 
    Superuser created successfully.
    Installing custom SQL ...
    Installing indexes ...
    Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
```

but when I check if the table and the graph were created, I find nothing!

I am using django 1.4 and neo4j 1.9.M05.

Here is how I declared my databases in settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
     'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
     'NAME': 'geodjango',
     'USER': 'postgres',


     }
}
NEO4J_DATABASES = {
    'default' : {
        'HOST':'127.0.0.1',
        'PORT':7474,
        'ENDPOINT':'/db/data/'
    }
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['neo4django.utils.Neo4djangoIntegrationRouter']
```

and I declared my models.py like this :

```
from neo4django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as gis                             

class Airport(models.NodeModel):
    name = models.StringProperty()
    iata = models.StringProperty()
    icao= models.StringProperty()

    city = models.Relationship('self',rel_type='isAT')

#geographical database for storing entities coordinates
class pointsOfInterest(gis.Model):
    nodeid = gis.IntegerField()
    longitude = gis.FloatField()
    latitude = gis.FloatField()

    # GeoDjango-specific: a geometry field (MultiPolygonField), and
    # overriding the default manager with a GeoManager instance.
    objects = gis.GeoManager()
```

thanks for your help

---

EDIT

When I run `python manage.py sqlall testapp` (where testapp is my app and after deleting the neo4j models , otherwise it won't work ), i am getting that sql that permit to create the table :

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "testapp_pointsofinterest" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "nodeid" integer NOT NULL,
    "longitude" double precision NOT NULL,
    "latitude" double precision NOT NULL
)
;
COMMIT;
```

after that I run `./manage.py syncdb` and ONLY the pointsOfInterest table is created (not the graph )

```
postgres@anas-desktop:/home/anas/Desktop/testNeo4Django$ ./manage.py syncdb
Creating tables ...
Creating table testapp_pointsofinterest
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
```

Any ideas why the nodes representing my models are not created in the graphdb?

Comment: Looks like it's not finding your models.  Do you have your "app" inclucded in `INSTALLED_APPS` in the settings.py file?

Comment: yes i included it :
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'testNeo4Django.testapp',
    'django.contrib.gis',
)
when i use only the PostGIS db, and run python manage.py sqlall testapp, i get the table that is going to  be created using the model (a proof that models.py is accessible)

Comment: can you add all the text before, "You just installed Django's auth system, ..."?

Comment: Django asked me to create a super user only the first time.
Now i am getting : 

postgres@anas-desktop:/home/anas/Desktop/testNeo4Django$ ./manage.py syncdb
Creating tables ...
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)

(nothing has been added )

Comment: try importing your `pointsOfInterest` model from the django shell, `python manage.py shell`.  It may give you a clearer error message.

Comment: that means you just need to fill the field values: `pointsOfInterest.objects.create(nodeid=1, longitude=1.0, latitude=1.0)`

Comment: Done :) 
I updated the question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there wasn't any problem at all !

The first time i ran `./manager.py syncdb` the pointsOfInterest table was created in the sql database and i didn't noticed that

For the following attempts, i was expecting this command to insert the neo4j models as a kind of 'root' nodes for the future nodes that will be inserted in the graphdb (while it seems that this command doesn't do this), and focusing on the fact that the previous table weren't added ( whereas it was added before , and Django doesn't replace existing tables )

Problem resolved !

Comment: Yep, neo4django doesn't build the in-graph type hierarchy until it absolutely has to- no syncdb necessary unless you're using another DB, as you are.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation Matt :)